# offsetof returning wrong value?

Tags: c

### Problem:

I am working on a very old game and *closed source*, so the only way to do any modification, is to use memory addresses, hook the functions and do the work - a very tedious job.

I am using IDA in order to decompile the functions and remake them in C, since the game uses structs to store data, IDA actually returns memory offsets, for example:

```
a1[177] += a1[177] * j_IsExtDefenseSuccessfull(a1[777] + 132 * v26) / 100; // Why is it using a1[177] instead of (a1 + 177)?
*((_WORD *)a1 + 112) += j_IsExtMonsterMoney(132 * v26 + a1[777]); // MonsterDieGetMoney -Actual offset is at 224
*((_BYTE *)a1 + 222) += j_IsExtDamageMinus(132 * v26 + a1[777]); // Correct - is it a1[222] the same?
*((_BYTE *)a1 + 223) += j_IsExtDamageReflect(132 * v26 + a1[777]); // Correct - is it a1[223] the same?
```

From the struct itself, a1 + 112 (MonsterDieGetMoney) is actually located at offset 224 by looking at the output of *offsetofreturn*

```
lpObj + 112 MonsterDieGetMoney = 58000
lpObj + 224 MonsterDieGetMoney = 0
a1 + 112 MonsterDieGetMoney = 58000
a1 + 224 MonsterDieGetMoney = 0
a1[224] = 0
**MonsterDieGetMoney offset = 224**
```

### Questions

1- Why if the offset is at 224, the actual offset is 112?
You can see that lpObj + 112 is returning the correct value.

2- Is it a1 + 223 the same as a1[233]?

3- Is there any easier method to determine what index/offset belongs to in the struct?
I have the complete struct in order to do the matching.

### Others

This is the code I used to debug:

```
void gObjExtItemApply(DWORD* a1)
{
    OBJECTSTRUCT* lpObj = (OBJECTSTRUCT*)a1;

    char Str[255];

    lpObj->MonsterDieGetMoney = 58000;

    //MonsterDieGetMoney
    sprintf_s(Str, "lpObj + 112 MonsterDieGetMoney = %d", *((WORD*) lpObj + 112));
    DebugY(Str);
    sprintf_s(Str, "lpObj + 224 MonsterDieGetMoney = %d", *((WORD*) lpObj + 224));
    DebugY(Str);

    sprintf_s(Str, "a1 + 112 MonsterDieGetMoney = %d", *((WORD*) a1 + 112));
    DebugY(Str);
    sprintf_s(Str, "a1 + 224 MonsterDieGetMoney = %d", *((WORD*) a1 + 224));
    DebugY(Str);

    sprintf_s(Str, "a1[224] = %d", (WORD)a1[224]);
    DebugY(Str);

    sprintf_s(Str, "MonsterDieGetMoney offset = %d", offsetof(OBJECTSTRUCT, MonsterDieGetMoney));
    DebugY(Str);
}
```

I present to you the very long struct - I manually went byte by byte adding the padding that C compiler should/would make, and with help of offsetoff I got some of the offsets.

```
struct OBJECTSTRUCT
{
    int m_Index; // 0

    int Connected; // 4

    char LoginMsgSnd; // 8
    char LoginMsgCount; // 9
    char CloseCount; // 10
    char CloseType; // 11

    struct _PER_SOCKET_CONTEXT* PerSocketContext; // 12

    UINT_PTR m_socket; // 16

    char Ip_addr[16]; // 20

    int UserNumber; // 36

    int DBNumber; // 40

    BYTE Magumsa; // 44
    // 1 null byte
    // 1 null byte
    // 1 null byte

    DWORD AutoSaveTime; // 48

    DWORD ConnectCheckTime; // 52

    DWORD CheckTick; // 56

    BYTE CheckSpeedHack; // 60
    // 1 null byte
    // 1 null byte
    // 1 null byte

    DWORD CheckTick2; // 64

    BYTE CheckTickCount; // 68
    // 1 null byte
    // 1 null byte
    // 1 null byte

    int iPingTime; // 72

    BYTE m_TimeCount; // 76
    // 1 null byte
    // 1 null byte
    // 1 null byte

    DWORD m_dwPKTimer; // 80

    short CheckSumTableNum; // 84
    // 1 null byte
    // 1 null byte

    DWORD CheckSumTime; // 88

    BYTE Type; // 92
    BYTE Live; // 93
    BYTE characterPos; // 94
    char AccountID[11]; // 95

    char Name[11]; // 106
    char LastJoominNumber[14]; // 117
    BYTE Class; // 131
    BYTE DbClass; // 132

    BYTE ChangeUP; // 133
    short Level; // 134
    // 1 null bytes

    int LevelUpPoints; // 136

    DWORD Experience; // 140

    DWORD NextExp; // 144 

    int Money; // 148

    WORD Strength; // 152
    WORD Dexterity; // 154

    WORD Vitality; // 156
    WORD Energy; // 158

    float Life; // 160

    float MaxLife; // 164

    float FillLife; // 168

    float FillLifeMax; // 172

    float Mana; // 176

    float MaxMana; // 180

    int BP; // 184

    int MaxBP; // 188

    int AddBP; // 192

    float VitalityToLife; // 196

    float EnergyToMana; // 200

    char m_PK_Count; // 204
    char m_PK_Level; // 205
    // 2 bytes null

    int m_PK_Time; // 208

    short X; // 212
    short Y; // 214

    BYTE Dir; // 216
    BYTE MapNumber; // 217
    short AddLife; // 218

    short AddMana; // 220
    BYTE DamageMinus; // 222
    BYTE DamageReflect;  // 223

    short MonsterDieGetMoney; // 224
    BYTE MonsterDieGetLife; // 226
    BYTE MonsterDieGetMana; // 227

    BYTE StartX; // 228
    BYTE StartY; // 229
    short m_OldX; // 230

    short m_OldY; // 232
    short TX; // 234

    short TY; // 236
    short MTX; // 238

    short MTY; // 240
    // 2 bytes null

    int PathCount; // 244

    int PathCur; // 248

    char PathStartEnd; // 252
    // 1 byte null
    short PathOri[15]; // 254

    short PathX[15]; // 284

    short PathY[15]; // 314

    char PathDir[16]; // 344

    DWORD PathTime; // 360

    char m_MoveGateNumber; // 364
    // 3 bytes null

    DWORD Authority; // 368

    DWORD AuthorityCode; // 372

    DWORD Penalty; // 376

    BYTE m_cAccountItemBlock;
    struct tagActionState m_ActState;
    BYTE m_ActionNumber; 
    DWORD m_State; 
    char m_StateSub; 
    BYTE m_Rest;
    char m_ViewState;
    BYTE m_ViewSkillState; 
    DWORD m_LastMoveTime;
    DWORD m_LastAttackTime;
    int m_DetectSpeedHackTime; 
    DWORD m_SumLastAttackTime; 
    DWORD m_DetectCount; 
    int m_DetectedHackKickCount;
    int m_SpeedHackPenalty; 
    BYTE m_AttackSpeedHackDetectedCount;
    DWORD m_PacketCheckTime; 
    BYTE m_ShopTime; 
    DWORD m_TotalAttackTime;
    int m_TotalAttackCount; 
    DWORD TeleportTime; 
    char Teleport;
    char KillerType;
    char DieRegen;
    char RegenOk;
    BYTE RegenMapNumber;
    BYTE RegenMapX; 
    BYTE RegenMapY;
    DWORD RegenTime; 
    DWORD MaxRegenTime; 
    short m_PosNum;
    DWORD LifeRefillTimer;
    DWORD CurActionTime;
    DWORD NextActionTime; 
    DWORD DelayActionTime; 
    char DelayLevel; 
    char m_PoisonBeattackCount; 
    char m_ColdBeattackCount;
    OBJECTSTRUCT* lpAttackObj; 
    short m_SkillNumber; 
    DWORD m_SkillTime; 
    char m_ManaFillCount; 
    char m_LifeFillCount;
    int SelfDefense[5]; 
    DWORD SelfDefenseTime[5];
    DWORD MySelfDefenseTime; 
    char m_Drink;
    int m_SkillDefense; 
    char m_SkillDefenseTime;
    int m_SkillAttack;
    char m_SkillAttackTime;
    int m_SkillAttack2;
    char m_SkillAttackTime2;
    int m_SkillAddLife; 
    int m_SkillAddLifeTime;
    int m_SkillHarden; 
    int m_SkillHardenTime; 
    int m_SkillMagumReduceDefense;
    int m_SkillMagumReduceDefenseTime;
    int PartyNumber;
    int PartyTargetUser;
    int GuildNumber;
    _GUILD_INFO_STRUCT* lpGuild; 
    char GuildName[11];
    int m_RecallMon;
    int m_Change; 
    short TargetNumber; 
    short TargetShopNumber; 
    short ShopNumber;
    short LastAttackerID;
    int m_AttackDamageMin;
    int m_AttackDamageMax; 
    int m_MagicDamageMin; // 164
    int m_MagicDamageMax; // 165
    int m_AttackDamageLeft;
    int m_AttackDamageRight;
    int m_AttackDamageMaxLeft; // 168
    int m_AttackDamageMinLeft; // 169
    int m_AttackDamageMaxRight; // 170
    int m_AttackDamageMinRight; // 171
    int m_AttackRating; // 172
    int m_AttackSpeed; // 173
    int m_MagicSpeed; // 174
    int m_Defense; 
    int m_MagicDefense;
    int m_SuccessfulBlocking;
    short m_MoveSpeed;
    short m_MoveRange;
    short m_AttackRange;
    short m_AttackType; 
    short m_ViewRange; 
    short m_Attribute; // 183
    short m_ItemRate;
    short m_MoneyRate;
    int m_CriticalDamage; 
    int m_ExcelentDamage;
    CMagicInf* m_lpMagicBack; 
    CMagicInf* Magic;
    char MagicCount; 
    BYTE UseMagicNumber;
    DWORD UseMagicTime; 
    char UseMagicCount;
    short OSAttackSerial; 
    BYTE SASCount; 
    DWORD SkillAttackTime;
    BYTE CharSet[11]; // DEFAULT 11
    BYTE m_Resistance[4];
    int FrustrumX[4];
    int FrustrumY[4]; // 200?
    VIEWPORT_STRUCT VpPlayer[75]; 
    VIEWPORT_STRUCT VpPlayer2[75];
    int VPCount; 
    int VPCount2;
    HITDAMAGE_STRUCT sHD[40]; 
    short sHDCount; 
    taginterfaceState m_IfState;
    DWORD m_InterfaceTime;
    CItem* pInventory; 
    BYTE* pInventoryMap;
    char* pInventoryCount; 
    char pTransaction;
    CItem* Inventory1;
    BYTE* InventoryMap1;
    char InventoryCount1;
    CItem* Inventory2;
    BYTE* InventoryMap2;
    char InventoryCount2;
    CItem* Trade;
    LPBYTE TradeMap;
    int TradeMoney;
    BYTE TradeOk;
    CItem* pWarehouse; 
    BYTE* pWarehouseMap; 
    char WarehouseCount;
    short WarehousePW; 
    BYTE WarehouseLock; 
    BYTE WarehouseUnfailLock;
    int WarehouseMoney; 
    int WarehouseSave; 
    CItem* pChaosBox; 
    BYTE* pChaosBoxMap; 
    int ChaosMoney; 
    int ChaosSuccessRate; 
    int ChaosLock; 
    DWORD m_Option;
    int m_nEventScore; 
    int m_nEventExp;
    int m_nEventMoney; 
    BYTE m_bDevilSquareIndex;
    BYTE m_bDevilSquareAuth; 
    char m_cBloodCastleIndex;
    char m_cBloodCastleSubIndex;
    int m_iBloodCastleEXP; 
    BYTE IsInBattleGround; 
    BYTE HaveWeaponInHand;
    short EventChipCount; 
    int MutoNumber;
    int UseEventServer; 
    BYTE LoadWareHouseInfo;
    BYTE m_Quest[50];
    BYTE m_SendQuestInfo;
    int m_SkyBossMonSheildLinkIndex;
    int m_SkyBossMonSheild; 
    int m_SkyBossMonSheildTime;
    int m_MaxLifePower;
    int m_WizardSkillDefense;
    int m_WizardSkillDefenseTime;
    int m_PacketChecksumTime;
    int m_CheckLifeTime;
    BYTE m_MoveOtherServer; 
    char m_BossGoldDerconMapNumber; 
    BYTE m_InWebzen; 
    char m_LastTeleportTime; 
    BYTE m_ClientHackLogCount; 
    BYTE m_ReqWarehouseOpen; 
    int NotAttackAreaCount; 
};
typedef OBJECTSTRUCT* LPOBJ;
extern  OBJECTSTRUCT* gObj;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> 1- Why if the offset is at 224, the actual offset is 112? You can see that lpObj + 112 is returning the correct value.

Pointer arithmetic is performed in units of the pointed-to type. In `(_WORD *)a1 + 112`, `(_WORD *)a1` is a pointer of type `_WORD *`, so it points to a `_WORD`, so `+ 112` adds the distance of 112 `_WORD` objects, which equals the distance of 224 bytes. `offsetof` produces an offset in bytes.

> 2- Is it a1 + 223 the same as a1[233]?

No, `a1 + 223` is a pointer, and `a1[233]` is the array element with index 233. Also 223 and 233 are different numbers. `&a1[223]` would be the address of the element with index 223, so it would be the same as `a1 + 223`. That is:

- The address `a1 + 223` is the same as the address `&a1[223]`.
- The address `a1 + 223` is not the same as the array element element `a1[223]`.

> 3- Is there any easier method to determine what index/offset belongs to in the struct? I have the complete struct in order to do the matching.

Easier in what sense? Easier to write in code or easier to count yourself? For code, use `offsetof`; that is what it is for. Note, however, that this sort of direct pointer arithmetic across members of structures must be done carefully to avoid problems because the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `_WORD` is presumably a 2-byte type. Pointer arithmetic is done in units of the type that the pointer points to.

`offsetof` returns the offset in bytes, and this is divided by 2 when adding to `(_WORD *)a1`.